# Google zxing api unable to decode barcode

Tags: java, zxing, bufferedimage

I am using google zxing api for java to decode a barcode png image.The code is as below.The function new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap).getText()) does not work properly for all the barcode images.Please let me know in case any other additional details are required and if there's any better way to decode barcode images using google zxing.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryDecoder;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader;

public class DecodeBarcode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage qrCodeImage = null;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String imgname = "img_file_name.png";
        qrCodeImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/pathToTheFile/" + imgname));

        try {
            LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(qrCodeImage);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            System.out.println("Decoded text===>" + new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap).getText());


        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("barcode was not decoded successfully");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless the barcodes are machine-generated test samples that are somehow guaranteed to be decoded, I think this is completely normal. When scanning barcodes, the fact that some barcodes are not recognized is a thing you need to handle. The scanner (human or machine) should just try again, and perhaps give up after some number of attempts.

Comment: HI @haraldK.The barcode image I am trying to decode is system generated and is decoded everytime I use an online decoding tool like"https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx", but for certain images my code always seem to fail,although both the tool and my code use the same API.I'll be uploading the barcode image file shortly.